# Facebook uploaded videos of another user

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am starting to be desperate, I am trying to get facebook uploaded videos of another user. I've been googling, trying everything but without success. I created facebook application, set Appl domains as subdomain.domain.cz, domain.cz and site url as https://subdomain.domain.cz.

When I try to get the list of videos I receive zero objects. I use following code:

```
$fb_page_id = "MY FACEBOOK USER ID";


$access_token_temp = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_APPLICATION_ID&client_secret=MY_APPLICATION_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials";

$json_token = file_get_contents($access_token_temp);
$decoded = json_decode($json_token);
$access_token = $decoded->{'access_token'};


$fields = "id,title,description,created_time,from,source";
$limit = 5;

$json_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{$fb_page_id}/videos?access_token={$access_token}&amp;fields={$fields}&amp;limit={$limit}&amp;type=uploaded";

$json = file_get_contents($json_link);

$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$feed_item_count = count($obj['data']);

echo "NUMBER OF OBJECTS RETURNED: ".$feed_item_count; // always returns 0
```

Comment: And what makes you think that would be possible without the other users permission?

Comment: I thought that if the uploaded video is public on the user's facebook profile, then it should be possible. If not, how could the user give the permission for the application to access his uploaded videos? I am creating web page for this user where he wants to display his videos.

Comment: You thought wrong. Public via the website/UI, does not mean freely available via API. And the user would grant that permission they same way, they would grant any other permission - by your app _asking_ them for that permission during login.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, in that case there is no way how to do it because I want to display videos once anybody visits the web page without any facebook login.